# Unittesting collections values that is changed through the test

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have several functions that take a dict as an argument and return it modified. In my unittests I want to test if functions' input is correct by checking a mock call's arguments. But doing so I get dict state after all modifications in a tested function, not the state on mock function call. Seems like mock saves called arguments using object links, not `copy()`. How can I avoid that? Am I missing something?

```
# app.py
def dict_modificator(inp_dict):
    inp_dict['foobar'] = 123
    return inp_dict

def tested_function():
    inp_dict = {'spam': 'eggs'}
    inp_dict = dict_modificator(inp_dict)
    inp_dict['ham'] = 456

# unittest.py
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_it(self):
        dict_modificator_mock = Mock(wraps=app.dict_modificator)
        with patch("app.dict_modificator", dict_modificator_mock):
            app.tested_function()

        args, _ = dict_modificator_mock.call_args
        self.assertEqual({'spam': 'eggs'}, args[0])
        # AssertionError: {'spam': 'eggs'} != {'spam': 'eggs', 'foobar': 123, 'ham': 456}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use side effects on the Mock to make a copy of the dictionary that's passed in

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_it(self):
        copy = {}
        def make_copy(x):
            for k, v in x.items():
                copy[k] = v
            return DEFAULT

        dict_modificator_mock = Mock(wraps=test.dict_modificator)
        dict_modificator_mock.side_effect = make_copy

        # copy = {'spam': 'eggs'}
        # use copy in your assertion
```

Comment: Yeah, self-made args/kwargs copying side_effect or decorator may be an OK workaround but I was looking if there is any std-lib solution.